# Stretching background image in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to achive this screen:

[image]

As you can see, i have to stretch the background image to bottom, left and right. But the anchor always should point to profile picture. How can I do this?

Comment: Will the profile picture not always be in the same place?

Comment: Are you creating this view in interface builder?

Comment: Profile picture will always be in vertical center. I am using interface builder.